# What does `if(!*str) ...` mean for a `char* str`?

Tags: c

What does `!*s` do in this function:

```
void f( char *s) {
    if( !*s ) {
        return;
    }
    f( s+1 );
    putchar( *s );
}

int main( void ) {
    f("kernighan");
    putchar('\n');
return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is `nahginrek`; which I think it swapped the 
left character with the right character and keeps doing it till it reaches the middle?

Comment: It's an obfuscated way of writing `if(*s == '\0')`.

Comment: The meaning of the `!` operator doesn't have anything to do with the return type of the function where it's used. Your question title is mildly confusing.

Comment: A "!" in front of any expression produces a bool value of false for non zero values. It's been quite a common coding practice for decades, both terse and clear though it may look a little strange when first learning C or C++.

Comment: The code is not swapping anything. It's using recursion to find the end of the string, and then prints the string backwards.

Comment: @doug well, not quite. It does result in type `int`, actually. Refer C11, §6.5.3.3/5

Comment: @Sourav, See §5.3.1.9. Also, the bool result of the "!" is the operand of an "if" statement in the op's example. Regardless, my point is that this has long been a common, and clear, coding practice in C and C++.

Comment: @doug `§5.3.1.9`? of? C++ spec? isn't it like C and C++ __are__ different languages?

Comment: @Sourav, Sorry, I'm so used to C++ that I went to the C++ interpretation of the code. The OP's code fragment represents a common idiom in both.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title, hopefully it is clearer now. If not, feel free to revert / change.

Answer (score 7):

It checks if the character pointed to by `s` is ascii null (NUL) '\0' which is the string delimiter (last char) in C strings.

`!*s` will be true if `*s` is `'\0'`.

Note that it is not the same as checking if `s` is `NULL` which means that the pointer `s` points to address zero.

Answer (score 3):

As others already mentioned,

```
 if( !*s )
```

is equivalent to

```
if( !(*s) )
```

or

```
 if( *s == 0 )
```

Just to add some reference, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.3, *Unary arithmetic operators*, paragraph 5,

> [...] The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

The whole block

```
if( !*s ) {
    return;
}
```

makes sure that the function returns if you've reached the null-terminator ([which has a value `0`](http://www.asciitable.com/)) of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It tests if the character pointed to by `s` is null (the ascii character `\0`). The `\0` character marks the end of the C-style string, so the test is basically checking to see if the recursion has reached the end of the string.

The logical not `!` is evaluated after the pointer is dereferenced `*s`. This is not a test on the validity of the pointer itself, that would look more like `if (!s)` or `if (s)`.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a pointer.

`*s` is dereferncing a pointer which gives the value stored in the location pointed by the pointer.

and `!*s` says fetch the value pointed by the pointer and check whether the value fetched is `\0` or not.